# Need help with restricted page for users

Tags: plugins, admin, membership

I have 3 pages and i want one of the three to be restricted for normal users. I want there to be members, who only can view the page after they have been approved by the admin. To view the page i want them to 1. Register 2. get approved by the admin 3. able to view the page. Is there a plugin for this? or any solution of any kind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a membership site that restricts content to certain membership levels.

There are several membership plugins available for WordPress and several reviews of the options.  One site what has several articles on membership plugins is: [chrislema.com](http://chrislema.com/category/memberships-plugins/)